# Bibloteca para Processing

Tags: java, java-processing

Tenho o código-fonte abaixo, mas para funcionar preciso de uma biblioteca que não consigo encontrar, o que eu posso fazer para resolver?

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import netscape.javascript.*;
import processing.video.*;

Bola bolinhas[];


PImage imagemparticula;

PGraphicsOpenGL pgl;
GL gl;

MovieMaker mm;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer musica;
FFT fft;


void setup() {
  size(800, 600, OPENGL);
  //mm = new MovieMaker(this, width, height, "hiphop_processing.mov",30, MovieMaker.H263, MovieMaker.HIGH);

  mm = null;

  imagemparticula = loadImage("particula.png");

  minim = new Minim(this);
  musica = minim.loadFile("music.mp3");
  musica.play();
  musica.loop();

  fft = new FFT(musica.bufferSize(), musica.sampleRate());

  bolinhas = new Bola [fft.specSize()];

  for (int i=0; i<bolinhas.length; i++) {
    bolinhas[i] = new Bola();
  }
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);

  background( 0 );
  image( bg, 0, 0, width, height);
}

void draw() {
  //background(bg);
  fill( 0, 30 );
  //image( bg, 0, 0, width, height );
  rect( 0, 0, width, height );
  image( bg, 0, 0, width, height);



  fft.forward(musica.mix);

  float centroX = width / 2;
  float centroY = height / 2;

  pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g;
  gl = pgl.beginGL();
  gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
  gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE);
  pgl.endGL();

  fill(255);
  text("Press space to record a video", 20, 20);

  for (int i=0; i<bolinhas.length; i++) {
    bolinhas[i].mover();
    bolinhas[i].desenhar();
    bolinhas[i].elastico(centroX, centroY, 100);
    float val = fft.getBand( i ) + 1;
    float forcaX = random( -val, val );
    float forcaY = random( -val, val );
    bolinhas[i].forca(forcaX, forcaY);
  }
  if ( mm != null ) {   
    mm.addFrame();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    if ( mm == null ) {
      mm = new MovieMaker(this, width, height, "hiphop_processing.mov",30, MovieMaker.H263, MovieMaker.HIGH);
    } 
    else {
      mm.finish();  // Finish the movie if space bar is pressed!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: isto e processing e a biblioteca que me pede é NETSCAPE

Comment: @Barofscas Dê mais detalhes, sobre o que você precisa (qual erro está ocorrendo), pois as informações na sua pergunta são muito vagas.

Comment: o erro que me da é a falta da biblioteca a qual nao consigo encontrar internet

Comment: Qual o nome da biblioteca?

Comment: NETSCAPE é o nome da biblioteca

Comment: Seria isso [aqui](https://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/build/shared/lib/netscape?spec=svn685&r=685#netscape%2Fjavascript)?

Comment: nao consigo sacar isso que pos

Comment: Não consegue baixar?

Comment: nao nao consigo

Comment: Tente baixar individualmente: [JSException](https://processing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r685/trunk/processing/build/shared/lib/netscape/javascript/JSException.class), [JSObject](https://processing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r685/trunk/processing/build/shared/lib/netscape/javascript/JSObject.class), [JSUtil](https://processing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r685/trunk/processing/build/shared/lib/netscape/javascript/JSUtil.class)

Comment: e agr adiciono estes ficheios onde?

Answer (score 1):

A lib Netscape.javascript em falta faz parte da JDK do Java.

[Netscape.JavaScript](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/package-summary.html)

Bastará ires localizares o caminho para o ficheiro plugin.jar que se encontra dentro de uma subpasta da instalação JDK, e adicionares ao classpath do IDE que utilizas.

Caso utilizes versões antigas (JDK < 1.2), o ficheiro plugin.jar aparece com o nome jaws.jar.

O caminho a adicionar ao classpath será algo do género:

..\jdk1.X.X\jre\lib\plugin.jar

..\jdk1.2.X\jre\lib\jaws.jar

Comment: mas adiciono onde isso?

Comment: Qual é o IDE que utilizas?
Eclipse, Netbeans, etc...

Comment: onde vejo isso? IDE que utilizo nao sei

Comment: Que programa utilizas para compilar o código...